# Error while inserting a new revision of a file programatically

Tags: apex, files, contentversion, contentdocumentlink

I am trying to upload a new revision of a file in ContentVersion object programmatically by Apex. I am getting the below error while inserting a new record of ContentVersion.

> 15:21:52:424 EXCEPTION_THROWN [13]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Document with ID: 0693i000000ERjc is already linked with the entity with ID: 0013i000002GYXM: Linked Entity ID: [LinkedEntityId]

As per my code, I am passing the `ContentDocumentId` and `ReasonForChange` so that it creates a new revision of it, but this is not working. Any pointers will be helpful.

```
ContentVersion vContentVersion = new ContentVersion();
vContentVersion.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8'));
vContentVersion.Title = fileName;
vContentVersion.PathOnClient = fileName;
vContentVersion.ContentDocumentId = contentDocumentId;
vContentVersion.ReasonForChange = 'Demo';
insert vContentVersion;
```

Also in the error message, `0013i000002GYXM` is the accountId.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on ContentVersion or ContentDocument?

Comment: Do. I didn't create any trigger. Do I have to?

Comment: Can you show us the full stacktrace, or at least line number, of this error? Are you inserting a `ContentDocumentLink`?

Comment: It's giving an error while inserting vContentVersion. Do I need to insert a record in ContentDocumentLink before inserting ContentVersion?

Comment: I'm asking for more context here because this error doesn't appear to come from the code you have shown us. `LinkedEntityId` is a field on `ContentDocumentLink`. So there is clearly more code involved, either here or in some other automation, that creates a link to an Account record.

Comment: Why don't you try to update the contentVersion with new versionData?